# How to Get all the image links & download using python

Tags: python, image, beautifulsoup

**This is my code**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re

print("Enter the link \n")
link = input()

url = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
content = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
links = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a',href=re.compile('http.*\.jpg'))]
print (len(links))
#print (links)
print("\n".join(links))
```

**When i give the input as**

```
http://keralapals.com/emmanuel-malayalam-movie-stills
```

**I get the output**

```
http://keralapals.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Emmanuel-malayalam-movie-mammootty-photos-pics-wallpapers-0.jpg
http://keralapals.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Emmanuel-malayalam-movie-mammootty-photos-pics-wallpapers-1.jpg
http://keralapals.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Emmanuel-malayalam-movie-mammootty-photos-pics-wallpapers-2.jpg
http://keralapals.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Emmanuel-malayalam-movie-mammootty-photos-pics-wallpapers-3.jpg
http://keralapals.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Emmanuel-malayalam-movie-mammootty-photos-pics-wallpapers-4.jpg
http://keralapals.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Emmanuel-malayalam-movie-mammootty-photos-pics-wallpapers-5.jpg
http://keralapals.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Emmanuel-malayalam-movie-mammootty-photos-pics-wallpapers-6.jpg
http://keralapals.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Emmanuel-malayalam-movie-mammootty-photos-pics-wallpapers-7.jpg
http://keralapals.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Emmanuel-malayalam-movie-mammootty-photos-pics-wallpapers-8.jpg
http://keralapals.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Emmanuel-malayalam-movie-mammootty-photos-pics-wallpapers-9.jpg
http://keralapals.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Emmanuel-malayalam-movie-mammootty-photos-pics-wallpapers-10.jpg
```

**But , when i give the input**

```
http://www.raagalahari.com/actress/13192/regina-cassandra-at-big-green-ganesha-2014.aspx
or 
http://www.ragalahari.com/actress/13192/regina-cassandra-at-big-green-ganesha-2014.aspx
```

**It Produces no output :(**

SO ,   I need to get the links of its original pics . This page just contain thumbnails . when we click the those thumbnails , we get the original image links .
I need to get those image links and need to download :(
Any help is really welcome .. :)

Thank You

Muneeb K

Comment: I see **two** questions: 1. `raagala...com` doesn't contain `'a',href=re.compile('http.*\.jpg')` links but you expect that it does. 2. It contains thumbnail links (how do they look in the html source?) and you don't know how to get links to full-sized images. It is a different question. Please, don't ask more than one question per Stackoverflow question. You can always link to your previous questions if you want to provide more context

Comment: Your second URL is not working because the image is not directly linked to in the href of the anchor tag. It is a img tag in nested in the anchor tag.

Comment: @IanLaird exactly, I've elaborated it into an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in second case the actual image urls ending with `.jpg` are inside the `src` attribute of `img` tags:

```
<a href="/actress/13192/regina-cassandra-at-big-green-ganesha-2014/image61.aspx">
    <img src="http://imgcdn.raagalahari.com/aug2014/starzone/regina-big-green-ganesha/regina-big-green-ganesha61t.jpg" alt="Regina Cassandra" title="Regina Cassandra at BIG Green Ganesha 2014">
</a>
```

As one option, you can support this type of links too:

```
links = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('http.*\.jpg'))]

imgs = [img['src'] for img in soup.find_all('img', src=lambda x: x.endswith('.jpg'))]
links += imgs

print (len(links))
print("\n".join(links))
```

For [this url](http://www.raagalahari.com/actress/13192/regina-cassandra-at-big-green-ganesha-2014.aspx) it prints:

```
http://imgcdn.raagalahari.com/aug2014/starzone/regina-big-green-ganesha/regina-big-green-ganesha61t.jpg
http://imgcdn.raagalahari.com/aug2014/starzone/regina-big-green-ganesha/regina-big-green-ganesha105t.jpg
http://imgcdn.raagalahari.com/aug2014/starzone/regina-big-green-ganesha/regina-big-green-ganesha106t.jpg
http://imgcdn.raagalahari.com/aug2014/starzone/regina-big-green-ganesha/regina-big-green-ganesha107t.jpg
...
```

Note that instead of a regular expression I'm passing [a function](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) where I check that the `src` attribute ends with `.jpg`.

Hope it helps and you've learned something new today.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply .. :D But , I want recursive search to  - /actress/13192/regina-cassandra-at-big-green-ganesha-2014/image61.aspx and find the big image .